# Flutter: Where I can add Text()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to tap on the screen, and change background color to random color. It works fine, but I want to add Text on the center of screen, help me please.
Maybe someone have ideas, Thank you!
I try to add multiple child to AnimatedContainer.
Tried to add text in GestureDetector, but it doesn't work correctly

TopScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TopScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child; //child widget

  TopScreen({this.child});

  @override
  State createState() => _TopScreenState();

  static _TopScreenState of (BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final _TopScreenState result = context.findAncestorStateOfType();
    return result;
  }
}

class _TopScreenState extends State<TopScreen> {
  Color _color = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedContainer(
          child: widget.child,
          color: _color,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        ),
    );
  }

  void setColor(Color color) {
    this._color = color;
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:solidsoftwaretest/TopScreen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: TopScreen(child: MainScreen())));

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              TopScreen.of(context).setColor(Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]);
              TopScreen.of(context).setState(() {});
            },

    );
  } //build
}
```

UPD: if I add Child (Text) to GestureDetector - gestureDetector works only on Text.

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Hey there!')
      ),
        onTap: () {
          TopScreen.of(context).setColor(Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]);
          TopScreen.of(context).setState(() {});
        }
    );
  } //build
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `Text` widget inside a `Container` & wrap it further in `GestureDetector`. In order to make `GestureDetector` work on the whole area, give the `Container` a transparent color as follows:

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    TopScreen.of(context).setColor(Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]);
      TopScreen.of(context).setState(() {});
  },
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text('Hey there'),
    ),
  );
```

Hope, it will help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put a `Column` inside your `AnimatedContainer`. The `Column` will hold multiple `Widgets`.
I've updated the code to show the full example.

```
ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839(
  child: Text('Bananas'),
)
```

---

```
class ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839({
    this.child
  });

  @override
  _ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839State createState() => _ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839State();
}

class _ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839State extends State<ScaffoldColorCenterText60597839> {
  Color _color = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedContainer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              widget.child,
              Text('A text widget')
            ],
          )
        ),
        color: _color,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it throws exception "EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY", "RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout."

Comment: I've updated the code to show full working example. There must be some issue with the child you are sending to the constructor. Not with this code itself.

Comment: same problem, maybe I need re-write all program